# An ascending chain of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, noetherian, wreath-product

Let $G$ be the restricted wreath product of two infinite cyclic groups, say $\langle g\rangle$ and $\langle x\rangle$. Say $B$ the base group of $G$ (suppose $x\in B$). Is it possible to find a strictly ascending infinite chain of subgroups which is not contained in the base group?

Comment: Do you mean the restricted wreath product (i.e. only finitely many nontrivial components in the base group) or the full wreath product? For the restricted one I think the answer is no,  but it is certainly yes for the unrestricted version, since you can find an infinite chain of finitely generated subgroups in an uncountable group.

Comment: I mean restricted, infact I also thought the answer was no, but I cannot find a good idea to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to 4.2.3 of [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=0191523151) by Lennox and Robinson, if $G$ is a virtually polycyclic group, then the integral groupring ${\mathbb Z}G$ is Noetherian as a right module. Applying this result with $G$ an infinite cyclic group can be used to prove that there is no such ascending chain of subgroups in the restricted wreath product.